# How to wrap a native library class that has both a view and methods in Flutter plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, view, flutter-plugin

In my Flutter plugin project, I need to expose a class in custom native libraries to plugin users. This class is different from the others I worked on in that it contains both a view and some methods. In Android apps, the class' view is usually created in layout xml file, and then in Activity/Fragment file, it is referenced through `findViewById()` and then its methods can be called. In iOS apps, the view is usually created in Storyboard, and connected with a variable in the controller with IBOutlet. With that variable, it can call the class' methods.

I did a search and found some information about using native views like this: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views.
But it only contains information on how to host native views in Flutter apps, not Flutter plugins. Is there a way to make both the view and the public methods available to the plugin users?

Comment: The linked article includes a section on registration in a plugin - see the section that starts "For plugin registration, modify the plugin’s main file..."

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you for pointing that out! I am able to get the native view available for Flutter in Android. There's still some issue with iOS. My question then is how to expose the methods associated with the view? I doubt if I can create any public methods in the native implementation and it will become available on the Flutter side. The linked article does not cover how to do this.